# which pair of notes can't be parallel in Counterpoint

Tags: theory, counterpoint

Lets say i have a 4 voice texture.  The first chord has a 5th between the soprano and bass but then in the second chord there is a 5th between bass and tenor.  That would be parallel 5ths or no? do I still have to avoid parallel 5ths in this scenario? its not the same pair of voices?

Answer (score 2):

**"Parallel 5ths"** is a contrapuntal term that refers to **two consecutive intervals**, in this case two consecutive intervals of a perfect fifth where both voices move in the same parallel direction to get from one fifth to the next.

So if the soprano sings a G and the bass sings a C, that's a perfect fifth to be sure, but not a *parallel* fifth. "Parallel" is necessarily implying motion. If the next chord after that was the soprano singing an A and the bass singing a D, then yes, that would be a parallel fifth since both voices moved in parallel (by major second, here) from one perfect fifth to another.

There are voice-leading rules about fifths, but keep in mind that **every major and minor triad already contains a perfect fifth** in it. It's good to be alert to perfect fifths when writing in this style, but the real trouble with perfect fifths comes when you start having voices that don't **move independently enough to counteract the strong consonance of the perfect fifth** interval.

Comment: oops i meant to say just a 5th instead of parallel 5th.  Could you re read my question and answer it please?

Comment: @GordonO The general principle is that perfect fifths in different voices is okay - in fact, inevitable and necessary - but be careful that you don't end up with parallel fifths in the same voices. There are some other rules you will want to know about as well.